# Showing calculation progress real time and retain progress even if the browser is closed

Tags: java, ajax, multithreading

Suppose, this is in any `jsp` with `servlet` project.

I clicked a button to calculate something, and the process will be done in a few steps or by using some synchronized threads that need nearly 5 hours.

If I close the browser window after a click, what will happen?
Will the calculation process stop or continue?

If its the latter (continue), and I log in to my account after 2 hours, what will I see?
I want to see the calculation progress real time.

What should i do?

Comment: You kick off the processes in the background? You need to keep some sort of status object that the threads update then use that status to display information to the user. The threads will keep running if your webserver does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of processing requires planning. There are many edge cases. What if the process is already running? What to do if the server terminates in the middle of processing? Can you restart? Can the processing be interrupted? Can every user start this processing, or just authorized ones?

Ok, now to an answer. You want to run the processing in a separate, background thread. See the  Executor classes.  Then you have to store the progress of that processing somewhere (think db here) and create another page to show that progress. You may also have to remember the user that started the processing, so that you know which of the progress information to show to the user requesting the progress.

So, simple! :)